# azure pipeline job to check for file changes in a specific directory with a git commit

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am working to create a job in a stage that determines if a particular git commit has any file changes in a specific directory. If so I want to run another job.

I tried below in a bash task:

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  awsCredentials: ${{ parameters.awsCredentials }}
  workingDirectory: envs/${{ parameters.environment }}
  script: |
  commitid=`git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD`
  changes=`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commitid| grep $(basename $PWD)`

Above changes is working on my workstation, but it is not returning any when i echo $commitid in the pipeline task.